# React Native Table Component, justify text in tables at the top instead of the center

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-table-component

In the react native table component, I am trying to justify the text at the top instead of the center.

For example
[image]

How would I go about having the text start at the top? What text or table property would I have to change?